# operation with all inputs, without type="checkbox"

Tags: jquery, html, input

I want to do some operation with input elements in **td**. I used for this:

```
            var inputElements = $('td > input', row);

            inputElements.each(function () {

               //some operation

            });
```

How can I except checkboxes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get all inputs in each cell, **except** checkboxes.

```
var inputElements = $('td > input:not(:checkbox)', row);
```