# Style all Inputs but checkbox and radio

Tags: css, checkbox, radio-button

I am trying to use a style where I use

```
input:not([type=checkbox]),
input:not([type=radio]){ ...
```

But clearly that won't work.  How can I use the styles I have written for all inputs but just these two?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You need to use a single combined selector instead of two selectors:

```
input:not([type=checkbox]):not([type=radio]) { ... }
```

This selects any `input` element that does not have the attribute `type=checkbox` and that does not have the attribute `type=radio`. The code in the question, with two selectors, selects all `input` elements that do not have the attribute `type=checkbox` and additionally all `input` elements that do not have the attribute `type=radio`, so it ends up with selecting all `input` elements.

Usual CSS Caveats apply. You may wish to use polyfill like [Selectivzr](http://selectivizr.com/) to cover old versions of IE.

Comment: I found I needed quotes around the word radio and the word checkbox, otherwise this works great, thanks!

input:not([type='radio']):not([type='checkbox'])

Answer (score 3):

If you can use javascript, specifically jquery, than you can use this

```
$("input:not(:checkbox):not(:radio), select").addClass('myClass');
```

which will add class `myClass` to all inputs(and selects) but radio and checkbox

taken from this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2893606/932473

Answer (score 1):

You need to style all the other types except these two, awful as it may be.

You could try to add a class to the ones you don't want styled, and then use this in your CSS:

```
 input:not(.not){ /*Whatever styling you use*/ }
```

Comment: I can't add to this html unfortunately without JavaScript.  I am using Drupal for my CMS, and we've used these inputs in multiple different scenarios at this point.

Comment: Can you use Javascript?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not.  I think I will have to add each type of input in this format `input[type="TYPE1"], input[type="TYPE2"]`  I just can't find a good enough list with all the types.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it inside a Javascript file, you could use this instead:

```
$("input").not(["type=checkbox"]).not("#id").each(function() {
```

I'm using it for example in a loop, excluding all the checkboxes and the element with id = id